# Visual Studio Winforms Project Hidden Startup Code

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

When creating a VB.NET Winforms Project in Visual Studio, there's a lot of code related to initialization that seems to be hidden. Is there a way to show it in order to see which statements run from the very beginning, through creation of `MyProject` and `MyApplication` objects, creation and exhibition of `SplashScreen` and finally definition and creation of `My.Application.ApplicationContext.MainForm`?

That is, a Console application project has a `Sub Main()` that is visible, I presume a Winforms Application should have one too, but it is hidden and packed with the routines that create instances for SplashScreen, main Form and etc. I would like to see and understand better this flow.

Thank you!

Comment: If you mean the form initializer then in the top right corner in the **Solution Explorer** click on the button with three files on the left of **<>** then click the little arrow of your form and open **Form.Designer.vb**

Comment: @Mederic, no, I mean the application as a whole. That is, a Console application project has a `Sub Main()` that is visible, I presume a Winforms Application should have one too, but it is hidden and packed with the routines that create instances for SplashScreen, main Form and etc. I would like to see and understand better this flow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Click on Project --> Properties --> Application Tab --> View Application Events Button (bottom right of the tab).

Here you can create an [Application.Startup() Event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.applicationservices.windowsformsapplicationbase.startup?view=net-5.0), which is equivalent to `Sub Main` in a Console Application; at least it's the first place you should place code that needs to run.  *Use the DropDowns across the top of the code editor; change "MyApplication" to "(MyApplication Events)", and change "OnCreateMainForm" to "Startup".

Here you can also view the Constructor `New()` and `OnCreateMainForm()`, which is where the startup form is created.  Below is an example of all these together:

```
Option Strict On
Option Explicit On
'------------------------------------------------------------------------------
' <auto-generated>
'     This code was generated by a tool.
'     Runtime Version:4.0.30319.42000
'
'     Changes to this file may cause incorrect behavior and will be lost if
'     the code is regenerated.
' </auto-generated>
'------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices

Namespace My

    'NOTE: This file is auto-generated; do not modify it directly.  To make changes,
    ' or if you encounter build errors in this file, go to the Project Designer
    ' (go to Project Properties or double-click the My Project node in
    ' Solution Explorer), and make changes on the Application tab.
    '
    Partial Friend Class MyApplication

        <Global.System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()>
        Public Sub New()
            MyBase.New(Global.Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.AuthenticationMode.Windows)
            Me.IsSingleInstance = False
            Me.EnableVisualStyles = True
            Me.SaveMySettingsOnExit = True
            Me.ShutdownStyle = Global.Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.ShutdownMode.AfterMainFormCloses
        End Sub

        <Global.System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()>
        Protected Overrides Sub OnCreateMainForm()
            Me.MainForm = Global.VB_Scratch_WinForms.Form1
        End Sub

        Private Sub MyApplication_Startup(sender As Object, e As StartupEventArgs) Handles Me.Startup

        End Sub

    End Class

End Namespace
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you are asking for is buried in a mixture of locations.  The Console Sub Main() is just equivalent to whatever you dictate is the "Startup Form" under your Application settings; typically Sub Main() is equivalent to my Mainform_Load. In the solution explorer if you go through "My Project" (make sure you hit "Show all files" above the name of your application" and expand all the trees, you will see files such as Application.Designer.vb, Resources.Designer.vb, and Settings.Designer.vb which will show you auto-generated information pertaining to your project.  These are all loaded before the startup form is even initialized.

You can also use ApplicationEvents.vb (located under the Application tab under My Project) which shows you and allows you to call code before the startup form is created.

All of these parts together might be what you are interested in seeing. But as mentioned, most of it is beneath the hood and the Sub Main() is really whatever you want it to be in a Windows Form Application.

Hopefully these files help.