# How do you add command line switches to VB.NET WinForms application (when run from CMD)?

Tags: vb.net, command-line-arguments

I am creating a GUI-based application (VB.NET); I want it to have switches (such as `-s`, `-r`, `-a`, etc.) when run from the command line and not display the GUI.

I have already tried a plethora of methods, but they do not work, even the ones from Microsoft themselves.

Please help me. I have been researching for a day now.

Comment: What doesn't work? Can you show what you have tried? Have you checked [Environment.CommandLine](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.commandline)? Are you testing this in the Visual Studio IDE? Have you tried to use the `Project -> Properties -> Debug -> Command Line Arguments` tools?

Comment: Yes, I have tried the `Environment.CommandLine` but the switches don't work. The `For each args` method also doesn't work.

Comment: If it didn't work then you did it wrong. If you don't show us what you did, we can't see what you did wrong. ALWAYS post the relevant code.

Comment: You're looking for the `Application.Startup()` event.  See [my example here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44827038/2330053) for how to find it.  From the Remarks section: "You can use the Cancel property of the e parameter to control the loading of an application's startup form. When the Cancel property is set to True, the startup form does not start. In that case, your code should call an alternate startup code path.  You can use the CommandLine property of the e parameter or the CommandLineArgs property to access the application's command-line arguments."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set your startup form to `.visible = false`.

Then in the `Form_Load` event:

```
' Loop through the passed arguments
For Each argument As String In My.Application.CommandLineArgs

 ' Do stuff. i.e.:

 if argument = "-s" then
    ' Do something
 End if

 if argument = "-r" then
    ' Do something
 End if

 if argument = "-a" then
    ' Make the form visible
    Me.Visible = True
 End if

Next
```

Also, if you're planning to never use the GUI, just make a console app instead of a winforms app.